How do CPUs evenly occupy a PIPT L2 larger than associativity x page size?
Context
I was researching memcpy bandwidth of different platforms on different buffer sizes, and some of the runs showed much worse results, despite me doing what seemed like an appropriate amount of reads/writes, and there being virtually no background activity in the OS (all my runs are on Linux).
Further research revealed that the noise was coming from unoptimal L2 utilization due to uneven L2 set usage. Here is how I came to that conclusion: for one particular platform, I obtained Virtual->Physical mappings, and extracted bits from the physical addresses of the copied cachelines to get the L2 set index. The number of full L2 sets correlated nicely with bandwidth drops.
The L2 in question is PIPT, 8-way associative, with 2 banks, total size 256KB. This means there are 256K / 2 / 64 / 8 = 256 sets in each bank. Indexing 256 banks requires 8 bits. Since 6 bits are used as offset, and 1 bit selects the L2 bank, this means of the 8 bits, 8 - (12 - (6 + 1)) = 3 bits come from the upper 48 bits of the physical address (that is, the part that is actually different from the virtual address). And while the virtual addresses in memcpy are obviously sequential, the physical addresses do not have to be (and aren't, I looked at the mapping), which explains the slowdown.
The question
However, I observed this behaviour only on some of the platforms. For example, Cortex-A73 doesn't seem to demonstrate this behaviour at all (I suspect the L2 is sliced), and on Zen4 and Intel Tiger Lake I see very mild performance drops (<10%), while other platforms (RISC-V cores in particular) slowed down by up to 50%!
The slowdown makes sence to me. What I don't get is how do these other platform deal with it? From my reading, L2 is not usually sliced on platforms where it's not the LLC, and straight bits from the address are used for indexing instead. For any L2 that is larger than PAGE_SIZE x ASSOCIATIVITY x BANKS, this would mean there are set conflicts possible, depending on the VA->PA mapping. Take Zen4: it has a 1MB, 8-way associative L2 cache. Depending on the amount of banks, this would mean that up to 6 bits have to come from the part of the upper 48 bits of the address.
Is the operating system somehow taking the L2 indexing scheme into account when setting up the pagemap?
Do all large L2 caches secretly have a lot of of banks?
Am I missing something?

For your first question I believe the term is "page coloring" / "cache coloring".

Which, I believe, is not implemented in Linux. If you can point me to somewhere where it is, I would appreciate it a lot.

Maybe prefetching. Try accessing a complex (random-like) pattern of addresses. Do banks help here? Banks are for concurrent accesses, aren't they?

I am not sure how prefetching can help here, considering it leads to the same addresses being loaded from (even if earlier), thus the same L2 sets being used.

How can it be the L2 that make 50% difference?  That can only be the L1.  If it is PIPT and the physical map is not in order, then the same analysis will apply to L1.

The L1 is technicall physically indexed, but since it's so small, only the lower 12 bits of the address are used for the index, which are the same between the physical and virtual address.

Still doesn't make sense that L2 would have this affect.  There are some chip heuristics which recognize copies and zeros (specifically, I believe ARM has these).  There is no need to put the source data in caches, if they are immediately discarded.  ARM also has a write buffer and a multitude of page attributes for using these features.

Where can I read more about these heuristics for copies and zeroes? Sounds very interesting

Interestingly, the manual for the Cortex-A72 actually shows how the indexing works! See here: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100095/0002/system-control/aarch64-register-descriptions/ram-index-operation?lang=en
For example, for L2 data, it lists: PA[5:4] for "data bank", PA[6] for "tag bank", and PA[16:7] for "row select" (which I assume is the set). So I don't see how this would sidestep any of the issues with uneven set usage.

It is also not really clear how the L2 is scaled down from the theoretical maximum of 8MB down to 1MB on A73. The TRAM suggests that 16 ways and 64b CLS are fixed. However, there are several configurations of tag banks, data banks, and set count, which all lead to different L2 indexing.

Are you sure the slowdown is coming from the data cache and not something else like the MMU TLB? For large copies TLB misses can start to add up.

Yes, I am sure. I collected performance counters for dTLB and sTLB misses. They do not show any correlation with the observed slowdown, unlike the number of full L2 sets. These buffers are also not "large", they are at max L2/2 size, so ranging from 32KiB to 128KiB.

I have a little bit of a follow-up. Two features help significantly with this problem: Transparent Huge Pages, and L2 prefetch. THP basically makes the problem go away, as all bits of the index once again are taken from the virtual address. L2 prefetch just makes the effect less obvious, because it brings lines into L2, which it might be able to do regardless of half (or more) of your cache effectively being "cut off" by bad indexing.

However, I also ran some tests on Zen4 with all prefetchers turned off, and THP disabled. This still somehow worked OK, hinting that Zen4 might have some fancier L2 indexing scheme going on. Possibly "skewed-associative" caches: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/165123.165152 (my understanding is that it means different banks use different indexing)
